# How to show and save device base64 Image in ListView Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I convert the base64 datas to image, but it has not display on Listview imagecell.
And I want to save the image to the device, when the imagecell is clicked. How can I save image?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Can't really tell about why the data is not being populated in the listview.
But in order to use the local storage in xamarin forms, you can use this plugin from xamarin components

https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage

And once you get this installed via nuget you can use it like

```
IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("ImageStorage",CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("pic.png",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await file.WriteAllTextAsync(imageByteArray);
```

Comment: I did the listing image in listview, I applied what you said to save image, but It doesn't save gallery.

Comment: In order to save in gallery, you might have to save the files in the DCIM folder. Try to save the image in /DCIM/Camera/ folder, see if you get the image in gallery. I am not sure about this though.